# How to make draggable custom dialogue box in Tinymce 5.3.1

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

I've created a new plugin that opens an URL in dialogue box (url dialogue box using openUrl) but the problem is this dialogue box is fixed position, not draggable. In previous version 4.8.1
 all the dialogue boxes were draggable/movable. I need the same behavior, anyone has any idea how can I make dialogue box draggable?

[image: Screen shot of dialogue box, fixed position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a new property to make all the modal dialogs draggable. Use the draggable_modal option to enable dragging for modal dialogs.

```
Code Example:
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  draggable_modal: true
});
```

Reference:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#draggable_modal